# Is it OK to repot a small echo Echinopsis uhascua (Red Torch Cactus) while flowering?

Tags: cactus, repotting, flowering

I purchased my plant on line receiving it about 10 days ago.  It's been out of the sun acclimating to our hot climate since and one of three flower buds opened today.  It is about 2 inches (5 cm) high; it ok to repot it while flowering or should I wait until the flowers are spent?

I live in Southern California, BTW..